# Can't query more than 2000 records on external data source object

Tags: soql, query, externalobjects

I understand query_all and query_more, but I can't seem to get more than 2000 records from an external data source object.  I've tried this a few ways, and below is Python.  Note that if I use the (commented-out) Asset query, the initial results['done'] is false and we get all (250K) records.
However, on items_my_Sharepoint__x (fake name for this post), 2000 records are returned and the initial results['done'] is True.
Any thoughts on why this is and how to get more than 2000 records on this external data source object?

```
i=0  
query = "SELECT DownloadUrl__c,  Name__c FROM items_my_Sharepoint__x"
#query = "SELECT Id FROM Asset"
results = SF.sf_service.query(query)
for record in results['records']:
    i=i+1

print results['done']

while (results['done']==False):
    results = SF.sf_service.query_more(results['nextRecordsUrl'], True)
    for record in results['records']:
        i=i+1
print i
```

Comment: What is the "Server Driven Pagination" setting on the external object?
[Too many records received from external data source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318320&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: There is a similar question around the 2000 record limit against external objects [How to overcome 2000 records limit for external object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/126238/102)

Comment: Server Driven Pagination is not a setting on the external object :/

Comment: COUNT query times out for the external object (runs fine on Asset); and it seems maximum OFFSET value is 2000 :/

Comment: Hmm. It's been a while since I've looked at external objects and Salesforce Connect, so I don't want to steer you in the wrong direction. As best I can tell it should be a [setting on the external data source that drives the external objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.odata_paging.htm&type=5).  Another option might be to try manually paging by defining an [`OFFSET` in the SOQL query](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.odata_considerations_api_queries.htm&type=5). Again, I'm not an expert in this area and I don't want to send you on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Is it possibly a limitation of the underlying OData source not supporting `$skip`?

Comment: @DanielBallinger it's possible there's a 2000 OFFSET limit (less than 2000 works).  Maybe my understanding of external data source objects isn't so great - does the external data source object actually have its own records (in Salesforce) and we're querying against that?  or does the query run against the external data source directly and there are no records for the object in Salesforce?

Comment: @DanielBallinger - and thanks for your comments